# How can I create a simple web proxy server?

Tags: node.js, proxy, centos7

Basically the use-case is this:

Open a website > receiving the content from other website (and interacting with it like if it was the original link), so not just html but being able to log in, etc.

The thing is: I want to use my server as a bridge/proxy. (Like https://www.croxyproxy.com/ or https://www.proxysite.com/). For example: let's say I go to https://whatismyipaddress.com/, instead of seeing my real ip, I would like to see my server's ip.

How can I accomplish that? Please help me clarify the approach (and what stack can I use). I'm totally lost after googling a lot, so far I've found this:

- http://greim.github.io/hoxy/
- https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy-app
- https://github.com/mswjs/http-middleware

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you got a node.js server setup already? If not I'd suggest you look into the [`express`](https://npmjs.com/package/express) documentation.

Comment: @Tyler2P the thing is that I don't want to need to setting up ip/port in the browser config to being able to use it. I don't really even need a form like the websites shared as example, it just need to 'forward' the entire request (this is the flow: a user enters mydomain > they see the other website with full capabilities. And 'the other website' sees everything coming from 'my server ip'). Can I do it with express? How? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd need to setup a express server then send them to a HTML page with an `<iframe>` linking the site you'd like to view.

Comment: @Tyler2P are you sure they will use my server's ip? As far as I understand, using an iframe will make them send the requests from their networks without using my server as a 'bridge'